# How do I create a new data frame with a few selected columns from another

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe which pulls several columns from a previously created dataframe.

I tried using different formats (commas, etc)

```
a_df = topten_df["Median Age 2010", "Median Age 2011"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add another bracket:

```
new_df = old_df[["Median Age 2010", "Median Age 2011"]]
```

Comment: Just to add an explanation: the outer brackets are just an index operation like you normally do: `df["column_name"]`. The inner brackets are because you are using a list to select multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the list of column names in the index to fetch multiple columns.

```
a_df = topten_df[["Median Age 2010", "Median Age 2011"]]
```